# Pandas merge rows with ids in separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

Total meltdown here, need some assistance.

I have a DataFrame with +10m rows and some 150 columns with two ids, looking like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1' : [1,2,5,3,6,4]
              ,'id2' : [2,1,np.nan,4,np.nan,3]
              ,'num' : [123, 3231, 123, 231, 6534,2394]})


    id1 id2 num
0   1   2.0 123
1   2   1.0 3231
2   5   NaN 123
3   3   4.0 231
4   6   NaN 6534
5   4   3.0 2394
```

Where row index 0 and 1 are a pair given id1 and id2, and row index 3 and 5 are a pair in the same way. I want the table below, where the second row pair is merged with first row pair

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1' : [1,5,3,6]
              ,'id2' : [2,np.nan,3,np.nan]
              ,'num' : [123, 123, 231, 6534]
              ,'2num' : [3231, np.nan, 2394, np.nan,]})


    id1 id2  num  2_num
0   1   2.0  123  3231.0
1   5   NaN  123  NaN
2   3   3.0  231  2394.0
3   6   NaN  6534 NaN
```

How can this be archived using id1 and id2 and labeling all following columns from "id row 2" with "2_"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres one a merge based approach ,(thank you @pirSquared for improvement). i.e

```
ndf = df.merge(df, 'left', left_on=['id1', 'id2'], right_on=['id2', 'id1'], suffixes=['', '_2']).drop(['id1_2', 'id2_2'], 1)
cols = ['id1','id2']
ndf[cols] = np.sort(ndf[cols],1)
new  = ndf.drop_duplicates(subset=['id1','id2'],keep='first')
```

```
  id1  id2   num   num_2
0  1.0  2.0   123  3231.0
2  5.0  NaN   123     NaN
3  3.0  4.0   231  2394.0
4  6.0  NaN  6534     NaN
```

Comment: I'd try this `df.merge(df, 'left', left_on=['id1', 'id2'], right_on=['id2', 'id1'], suffixes=['', '_2']).drop(['id1_2', 'id2_2'], 1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir suffixes are beautiful. Wish I think the same way

Comment: Well my suggestion doesn't quite work, but yes `suffixes` help (-:

Comment: My suggestion produces 6 rows where 2 of them are unnecessary.

Comment: Oh God , you think abt getting solution in one line. :0. I was literally worrying abt the columns

Comment: This one scales to an arbitrary number of columns, except for the two ids, thats good

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to sort each pair of ids so that we group by them.

```
cols = ['id1', 'id2']
df[cols] = np.sort(df[cols], 1)

df.set_index(
    cols + [df.fillna(-1).groupby(cols).cumcount() + 1]
).num.unstack().add_suffix('_num').reset_index()

   id1  id2   1_num   2_num
0  1.0  2.0   123.0  3231.0
1  3.0  4.0   231.0  2394.0
2  5.0  NaN   123.0     NaN
3  6.0  NaN  6534.0     NaN
```

Comment: How is this possible. I scratched my head to use merge.  I succeed half. Later thought of a different approach i.e sort. You already put that here . 14 mins ago

Comment: And next time, you'll remember this moment and be much quicker.  Same as I have to thank @Psidom for being able to respond quickly here (-:

Comment: Sir I put my merge based answer there. anything that can be improved other than column names?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df[['id1','id2']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['id1','id2']].values, axis=1)).fillna('tmp')
print (df)
   id1  id2   num
0  1.0    2   123
1  1.0    2  3231
2  5.0  tmp   123
3  3.0    4   231
4  6.0  tmp  6534
5  3.0    4  2394

df1 = df.groupby(['id1','id2'])['num'].apply(list)
print (df1)
id1  id2
1.0  2.0    [123, 3231]
3.0  4.0    [231, 2394]
5.0  tmp          [123]
6.0  tmp         [6534]
Name: num, dtype: object

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist(), 
                  index=df1.index, 
                  columns=['num','2_num'])
        .reset_index().replace('tmp', np.nan)

print (df2)
   id1  id2   num   2_num
0  1.0  2.0   123  3231.0
1  3.0  4.0   231  2394.0
2  5.0  NaN   123     NaN
3  6.0  NaN  6534     NaN
```

Comment: I get a: TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()

Comment: Then try `tmp` change to some `int` value not in `id1`, `id2` like `-100` or `1000` or `-1`

Comment: Sorry, typo, my bad!